# Restfb - error publishing a Checkin

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

i'm trying to publish checkin in facebook with the standart code from restfb but i'm getting an error.

The code i'm using:

```
    Map<String, String> coordinates = new HashMap<String, String>();
    coordinates.put("latitude", "37.06");
    coordinates.put("longitude", "-95.67");
    FacebookType publishCheckinResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/checkins", FacebookType.class,Parameter.with("message", "message"),
            Parameter.with("coordinates", coordinates),
            Parameter.with("place", 1234)
    );
```

when facebookClient is initialized with the access token.

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#100) Requires a valid Place Page ID (code 100, subcode null)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1050)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:967)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:900)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:841)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.publish(DefaultFacebookClient.java:420)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.publish(DefaultFacebookClient.java:440)
at FacebookUpload.facebookInit(FacebookUpload.java:45)
at FacebookUpload.main(FacebookUpload.java:55)
```

I think the token is good because i succeded publishing a photo.
Somebody knows why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes around `placeId` which makes it an invalid Place id as the error says.
Try to remove them!

**Update:**

According to the documentation, you have to pass the id of the Page of the place you're checking in.

To get a place with restfb, you have to do something like that:

```
Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("cocacola", Page.class);
page.getId() // that's what you want
```

Also, the creation of checkin is deprecated in the [graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/checkin) and they suggest that you create a post instead.

Comment: As long as `placeId` is defined in the code, of course.

Comment: Thanks, but how i know what placeId i should put there? The code example in restFB wrote there 1234 but it's not working for me and showing the same error

Comment: I just updated the answer. "1234" was just a "placeholder" in the documentation to tell you that you have to provide an id.

Comment: Thank you a lot! if it's deprecated in graph API i can't actually use it